# Como ordena a lista, sem números repetidos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Foi me dada essa lista para ordena sem os números repetidos. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer?

```
lst = [54,54,93,93,77,77,44,44]

def bubbleSort(lst1):
    for x in range(len(lst1)-2,0,-3):
        for y in range(x):
            if lst1[y]>lst1[y+1]:
                temp = lst1[y]
                lst1[y] = lst1[y + 1]
                lst1[y+1] = temp            


print(lst)
bubbleSort(lst)
print("Ordenado ....")
print(lst)
```

Comment: Como assim ordenar sem repetidos ? Você quer ordernar ou quer retirar os repetidos ? Ou fazer ambas asa ações separadamente ?

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de fazer isso é transformar sua `list` em um [`set`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp), que é um tipo de lista que tem como característica ter elementos únicos, depois utilizar a função [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) que vai te retornar uma `list` ordenada

```
lst = [54,54,93,93,77,77,44,44]

# Transformar em set
lst = set(lst)
print('set',lst)

# aplicar o sort
lst = sorted( lst ) # crescente
#lst = sorted( lst , reverse=1 ) # decrescente

print('list',lst)
```

<sup>[Exemplo online](https://ideone.com/RYuT3W)</sup>